# How to use OmitXmlDeclaration and QuoteChar in c# when saving xml

Tags: c#, xml

i have some XML files and i have wrote a c# application to check missing elements, nodes and save it back. In my XMLs attributes are use single quotes (ex: `<Person name='Nisala' age='25' >`). But when saving C#  application convert those quotes to double quotes. Then i found following code  to save using single quotes

```
using (XmlTextWriter tw = new XmlTextWriter(file, null))
                    {
                        tw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                        tw.Indentation = 3;
                        tw.IndentChar = ' ';
                        tw.QuoteChar = '\'';                    
                        xmlDoc.Save(tw);                    
                    }
                }
```

but it will append XML declaration there. then i found this code to remove xml declaration

```
XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
                xws.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
                xws.Indent = true;
                xws.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(file, xws)){
xmlDoc.Save(xw);
}
```

then again XML declaration is appending to text. How can i use both of them?
i have tried following code too, but no use of it

```
XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
xws.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
                xws.Indent = true;
                xws.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;                
                using (XmlTextWriter tw = new XmlTextWriter(file, null))
                {
                    tw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                    tw.Indentation = 3;
                    tw.IndentChar = ' ';
                    tw.QuoteChar = '\'';               
                    using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(tw, xws))
                    {
                        xmlDoc.Save(xw);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML declaration is written by calling `WriteStartDocument` on the `XmlWriter` implementation.  The behaviour of this is can be altered when you use the recommended `XmlWriter.Create` with `XmlWriterSettings`.

However, the recommended method doesn't allow you to change the quote character.

The only solution I can think of is to create your own writer, deriving from `XmlTextWriter`.  You would then override `WriteStartDocument` to prevent any declaration being written:

```
public class XmlTextWriterWithoutDeclaration : XmlTextWriter
{
    public XmlTextWriterWithoutDeclaration(Stream w, Encoding encoding)
        : base(w, encoding)
    {
    }

    public XmlTextWriterWithoutDeclaration(string filename, Encoding encoding)
        : base(filename, encoding)
    {
    }

    public XmlTextWriterWithoutDeclaration(TextWriter w)
        : base(w)
    {
    }

    public override void WriteStartDocument()
    {        
    }
}
```

And use as you are now:

```
using (var tw = new XmlTextWriterWithoutDeclaration(file, null))
{
    tw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    tw.Indentation = 3;
    tw.IndentChar = ' ';
    tw.QuoteChar = '\'';
    xmlDoc.Save(tw);
}
```

Comment: I'm novice to development, could you please explain me how XML declaration not appending on that method? @charles-mager

Comment: Sure.  The declaration is written by the call to `WriteStartDocument`.  In this sub-class, we *override* this method and do nothing.  The original 'base' implementation is never called.